# Python For Loop But The index is increases 50

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for index in range(75)
    index += 5
    print(index)
```

But The printed was
5,6,7,...80
I want to add 5 in every time after print
I try This

```
x = 0
while x < 75 :
    x += 5
    print(x)
    if x >=  75 :
        x = 0
```

But its a while loop so I cant continue the another code

Answer (score 1):

**Use the `step` parameter of the `range` function:**

In `range(start, stop, step)` the `step` parameter determines how much the range increases by for every iteration:

```
for index in range(0, 75, 5):
    print(index)
```

Outputs:

```
0
5
10
15
...
60
65
70
```

Note that if we want to use the `step` parameter, we have to include the `start` parameter as well. For example, this won't work:

```
for index in range(75, 5):  # We need to include a `start` param.
    print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

The working mechanism of the `for` loop in Python is quite different from that in most other languages.

You can pass three variables to `range` with the signature: `range(<start>, <end>, <step>)`. For example:

```
for index in range(0, 75, 5):
    print(index)
```